# Multiple functions with different parameters in c#

Tags: c#

I would like to request what's the best way to handle the situation below.

I would like to call *populate* function for different instance with different parameters. I implemented *populate* function in each inheritance classes. But I don't know what's the best way to use it for hundreds of times.

(Eg *index* would be the total number of  country in the world).

```
public enum TCountry
{
   tAustralia,
   tUnitedKingdom,
   .. etc..
}
public enum TCity
{
   tSydney,
   tLondon,
   ... etc..
}
public int ProcessData ( string population, int index)
{
   switch (index)
   {
      case 0: 
         TypeAust aus = new TypeAust();
         retun aus.poulate( population, tAustralia, tSydney);
         // Different calculation Sydney -Aus
         DisplayAus(); // Display for Sydney - Aus

      case 1: 
         TypeUK uk = new TypeUK();
         retun uk.poulate( population, tUnitedKingdom, tLondon);
         // Different calculation for Londond - UK
         DisplayUK(); // Display for London - UK
      ....
      ... etc..
   }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: May I ask what is so different in the way you "populate" for different countries that it requires a concrete subclass for each ?

Comment: *populate* is just and example. I would like to do some kind of decoding and raw data conversion in *populate*. It is different for each subclass. I implemented super class and sub class. But the problem is I don't know how to consume them properly with hundreds of times.

Comment: You will get much better answers/help if you explain your real needs and not just some abstract ones.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to re structure my question and shoot it again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with a different design. Rather than working with that case statement, put all your types in a collection and call populate without knowing what specific type you're working with.

```
 List<TypeCountry> countries = new List<TypeCountry>() { new TypeUK(), TypeAus(), TypeUS() //ect };
 //use this list all throughout the program
```

Instead of you switch statement you can just do;

```
  return countries[index].populate( //args go here );
```

Then you can do other things like;

```
  int worldPop = countries.Aggregate((c, n) => c.Populate(//args) + n.Populate(//args));
```

In general you need to stop treating each type as if it's different from the next. Move your logic into the base class, get rid of code that has to refer to the type by name or requires specific checks for which inheriting type it is. For almost all cases you should be able to have a collection of the base classes type and pass it around and work on it without ever knowing what type the specific instance you're dealing with is. If that's not the case then you're doing inheritance wrong. If you have that big case statement then there is no point in even using inheritance because as far as I can tell you're not getting any of it's benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to see more of your actual needs and architecture but you could look into generics.

```
public int ProcessData<T>(string population) where T : BaseCountry, new() {
    var country = new T();
    Display(country);
    return country.Populate(population);
}

public void Display<T>(T country) where T : BaseCountry { ... }
```

You would use ProcessData like:

```
ProcessData<TypeAust>(99);
```

Your display method would be generic too. This way, your process data method is always constrained to work with anything that implements BaseCountry. BaseCountry would define an abstract or virtual Populate() method.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this so the logic is broken out into different classes:

```
public enum TCountry
{
   tAustralia,
   tUnitedKingdom
}
public enum TCity
{
   tSydney,
   tLondon
}

public abstract class TypeCountry
{
    public abstract int Populate(string population);
}

public class TypeAust : TypeCountry
{
    public override int Populate(string population)
    {
        // do your calculation with tAustralia, tSydney...
    }
}

public class TypeUK: TypeCountry
{
    public override int Populate(string population)
    {
        // do your calculation with tUnitedKingdom, tLondon...
    }
}

public static class TypeCountryFactory
{
    public static TypeCountry GetCountry(TCountry country)
    {
        switch (country)
        {
            case TCountry.tAustralia:
                return new TypeAust();
            case TCountry.tUnitedKingdom:
                return new TypeUK();
        }
    }
}

public int ProcessData (string population, int TCountry)
{
    TypeCountry country = TypeCountryFactory.GetCountry(TCountry);

    return country.Populate(population);
}
```